# How to bring App to App Home screen when app crashes in iOS

Tags: ios, sdk, crash

Team,

We have a requirement, In my app i am going inside and if app crashes the app is closing, Is there any way that we can recognise the crash and take the app to home screen.

Please let me know.

Comment: you should handle the crash, put try catch but can't navigate to other screen

Comment: @techloverr you should not try catch every single line of code and those would also not help you catching non exception based crashes.

Comment: he want to open a home page when some exception occurs so I suggested

Answer (score 0):

If your app crashes, then it will automatically show the home screen and exit the app.

You can get crash reports via the following way:

1. iTunes Connect if the app is distributed via TestFlight or the App Store (requires the user to have opted-in sharing this data)
2. Use Xcode Devices screen to get the crash reports directly from the device if you have access to it
3. Use a 3rd party solution that requires you to integrate an SDK to catch crash reports and send them to a server for symbolication and presentation

Comment: Thanks Kerni But what i need is i want to know the crash is happening dynamically and instead of quiting the app, i want to take the app to the home scree.

Comment: This is not recommended on iOS at all. The reason for a crash is that your app is in an highly unstable situation and memory can be corrupted and you could destroy your users data. You should avoid this at all costs.